# Angular and ngRx for standalone modules

Tags: angular, redux, ngrx, ngrx-store

I am wondering how I can implement standalone ngRx in Angular module. I want to develop new module that is completely standalone and I don't want to combine the state with parent module at all (Lazy or not lazy)

For example, I have a parent app (A) that has its own state/reducer/effects. Now, I want to develop a module in a new angular project (not the parent) and I want to create new module (B) that can be reused. in the new module I want to create its own state/reducers and ..., the problem now is when I use this module (B) I don't want to combine its state to parent app. It seems I can not have two instances of ngRx in application and ngRx can not be encapsulated in a module.

Thanks,

Comment: i didn't get your question clearly, can you elaborate more?

Comment: description updated